# ¿Como guardar archivo php+svg en caché?

Tags: php, svg

Tengo un archivo PHP que contiene una gran cantidad de imágenes SVG, por lo que tarda mucho en recargar la página. ¿Cómo podría guardar el archivo PHP (o solo la parte de SVG) en caché? ¿Existiría alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: Depende un poco de como muestras el archivo, ¿podriás explicarlo mejor?,¿los svg son estaticos o dinamicos?

Comment: En el archivo PHP que comento tengo un poco de código PHP que lo que hago es llamar a una base de datos y con un par de variables modifico el SVG (solo el viewbox) en el mismo fichero. Por lo demás el SVG es estático, son unas 130.000 líneas de código generadas, por lo que al cargar la página tarda bastante, y querría optimizar esto metiendo ese archivo PHP o solo la parte del SVG en caché. Otra opción sería quitar el PHP y dejar el archivo como solo SVG, y meter eso en caché. La primera prioridad es que ese SVG cargue rápido.